# Add new field in Fedex shipping method?

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, fedex

I have to add new field for shipping method in Fedex in admin panel?
If any idea about for that, please help asap.

**System > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Method > Fedex**

[image]

Thank you

Comment: You should explain a bit more what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have attach screenshot, which I want to add new field

Answer (score 2):

See [*`app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml`*](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml#L490). You will need to have the same parent Xpath in your module's *`system.xml`* file, e.g.:

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <carriers>
            <groups>
                <fedex>
                    <fields>
                        <your_field>
                            <label>Your Field</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>8</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
```

You can then read this value using `Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/fedex/your_field')`.

Comment: My credentials correct, i have two store in single magento, store 1 display Fedex shipping cost, but store 2 not displaying shipping cost, how can i solve this issue?

Comment: That’s a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, whoever try to help me. I have find solution for this.

I have change in mage/Usa/etc/system.xml. In system.xml, I have add tag as a new field. And some minor changes in model/shipping/carrier/Fedex.php.

Thank you again to all